# Can you manipulate web bluetooth chooser that shows after calling requestDevice()?

Tags: web-bluetooth

Can you manipulate web bluetooth chooser that shows after calling requestDevice()? Like getting the error message or the text displayed?

Comment: What do you mean by getting the error message? How would you like the web bluetooth chooser to look like?

Comment: Like get the text in the popup if the radio is off/disabled and assert it in selenium/cypress etc.

Comment: As mentioned by Reilly, have a look at https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/availability-async-await.html to detect whether Bluetooth is available. Users may still need to turn it on in the choose afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chooser can only be manipulated by configuring the filter which controls which devices are shown to the user. The chooser serves as a security and privacy barrier, preventing a site from learning about the devices in the user's vicinity without their explicit permission. The one additional signal which is provided and may be useful for your application is [navigator.bluetooth.getAvailability()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Bluetooth/getAvailability). This method returns whether the user's device is capable of connecting to Bluetooth devices, but not whether the Bluetooth capability is turned on or there are any devices nearby. If the device is capable of connecting to Bluetooth devices but the adapter is disabled then the browser will guide the user through enabling it as part of the chooser prompt.

Comment: is there a way I can mock the response of requestDevice() for testing purposes?

Comment: To mock the response of the API you will have to provide a mock for the entire Web Bluetooth API. If you're interested in automating testing using real Bluetooth devices then please star https://crbug.com/1040176.